# Build C# ASP.NET solution to different target folder VS2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, build

I have a web application that I've inherited and the application code is written such that it expects the application to sit in a sub folder

```
e.g. domain/sub/default.aspx
```

The application builds fine and I'm able to login but all the paths are expecting the /sub and resources aren't loading. The sub-folder structure needs to be maintained and I do not want to change working code on the application.

Is there any way to configure VS 2015 to build the web application in the sub folder? I'd prefer to not have to deploy in order to test properly

Answer (score 3):

sure!
right click on the project and select the **properties** in the **Build** tab you can change the output path to be like you want it.

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to do that for all the platforms, or you're screwed :)

Comment: also do it both in release and debug

Comment: I don't get that screen @silver I'm using VS2015, I'm right clicking the project in the Solution Explorer, is that correct?

Comment: right click on the project in the solution explorer (not the solution) -> properties

Comment: Ahh, I see, there was a Project and a website in the solution and I was clicking the website! Thank you

Comment: @silver I was about to (site wouldn't let me - I think there's a time limitation) but following the rebuild, it still uses the same URL in the browser and the issue persists. Any suggestions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127814/discussion-between-silver-and-daniel).